# Why the object return of `open` is not instance of `TextIO` or `BinaryIO`?

Tags: python-3.x, io, typing

According to the docs of `typing.TextIO` and `typing.BinaryIO`:

```
In [6]: TextIO?
Init signature: TextIO()
Docstring:      Typed version of the return of open() in text mode.

In [7]: BinaryIO?
Init signature: BinaryIO()
Docstring:      Typed version of the return of open() in binary mode.
```

I supposed that the object return of `open()` is instance of `BinaryIO` or `TextIO`, however:

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from typing import TextIO, BinaryIO

In [2]: f_text = open('test.txt', 'wt')

In [3]: f_byte = open('test.bin', 'wb')

In [4]: type(f_text), type(f_byte)
Out[4]: (_io.TextIOWrapper, _io.BufferedWriter)

In [5]: isinstance(f_text, TextIO), isinstance(f_byte, BinaryIO)
Out[5]: (False, False)
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate But why the `instanceof` for TextIO check does not raise exception as `isinstance([], List[str])`: ` TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks`

Comment: There's a similar issue/mystery with `sys.stdout` and friends.